# Latex in PySimpleGui window

Tags: pysimplegui

My question is very simple: is there a way to include latex or math expressions in PySimpleGui windows. I know that in matplotlib, we can use "rcParams['text.usetex'] = True " to enable typing Latex but I didn't find a way to insert my math symbols and equations in PySimpleGui. Help please ...

Comment: You can convert LaTeX or math expressions by maplotlib or sympy to png file, then show it in an Image element or a Graph element.